# Checkbox in ListView not working properly

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I am currently working on a ListBox with a an View with integrated Checkbox.
My problem is that my Checkbox is not changing anymore since I added a *onCheckedChange* Listener where I save the state of the item to the upper listbox. It is always marked as `unchecked` and my Listener always gets `true` as value for the parameter `isChecked`.

**My Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        ...
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"/>

    <TextView
        ...
        android:id="@+id/textNumber"/>

    <TextView
        ...
        android:id="@+id/textName"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the **CustomArrayAdapter**:

```
public class ContactArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

    private List<Contact> _contacts;

    public ContactArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contacts) {
        super(context, R.layout.contact_item, contacts);

        _contacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if ( convertView == null ) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()));

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
            // Some other stuff ...

            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(position, isChecked);
                    System.out.println(isChecked);
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public CheckBox checkBox;
        public TextView textName;
        public TextView textNumber;
    }
}
```

And last but not least.. My output. As you can see the state of the checkbox is never set to `checked` and the checkbox remains trying to set to `true`.

```
12-31 18:13:21.281  I/System.out﹕ true
12-31 18:13:21.513  I/System.out﹕ true
12-31 18:13:21.698  I/System.out﹕ true
12-31 18:13:21.850  I/System.out﹕ true
12-31 18:13:21.966  I/System.out﹕ true
```

Maybe there is an easy solution, but at the moment I just can figure out whats happening.

Thank you!

**Edit**: The problem is the line `((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(position, isChecked);`. It calls the methods `rememberSyncState()` and `requestLayout()`. Guess that is the problem... Any ideas?

Comment: what, when you tap the screen and check and uncheck the tick box it just prints true each time?

Comment: Exactly, also it doesn't mark the check box as checked

Comment: it should do if you click it, sounds like something else is stealing focus

Comment: have a look @ [This](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)!! example

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ContactArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

    private List<Contact> _contacts;

    public ContactArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contacts) {
        super(context, R.layout.contact_item, contacts);

        _contacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if ( convertView == null ) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()));

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
            // Some other stuff ...

            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckchangeListener(parent,position) );

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
class CheckchangeListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
        private ViewGroupparent;

        public CheckchangeListener(ViewGroup  parent,int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            this.parent= parent;
this.position= position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

             ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(position, isChecked);
                    System.out.println(isChecked);
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public CheckBox checkBox;
        public TextView textName;
        public TextView textNumber;
    }
}
```